# jainsip library showing null pointer exception in createAddress method

Tags: java, sip

I am trying to create an SIP INVITE request in java using the jainsip library. When I generate one from an address with the `createAddress` method:

```
 System.out.println(" get username: "+username);
 System.out.println("request ip:  "+ this.ip);
 System.out.println("request port"+ this.port);
 //System.out.println("<sip:"+username+"@"+this.ip+ ":" + this.port + ">");
 Address addressFrom = this.addressFactory.createAddress("<sip:" + username + "@" + this.ip + ":" + this.port + ">");
```

it throws this null pointer exception:

```
request ip:  192.168.1.4
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
request port7089
at sip.SipRequests.Invite(SipRequests.java:126)
at ContactList.btn_inviteActionPerformed(ContactList.java:140)
at ContactList.access$000(ContactList.java:21)
at ContactList$1.actionPerformed(ContactList.java:62)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: As your stacktrace contains no mention of a method named `createAddress` method, it is clear that your code is not getting into this method.  I can only conclude that `this.addressFactory` must be null.

Comment: but i checked addressFactory is working well @LukeWoodward

Comment: but when i changed the port value, the null pointer exception went above the request ip line @LukeWoodward

Comment: I'm assuming the code you've posted is from the `Invite` method as mentioned at the top of the stacktrace?  If so, which line is line 126?